# Is it okay to use MongoDB _id outside of MongoDB (Mongoose) context?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB with Mongoose.

I was wondering, if it is bad practice to use MongoDB IDs outside of MongoDB context. Since a lot of my objects need an ID to be identified, I was wondering if I just could use the IDs MongoDB gives them anyway or is that bad practice?

Best regards

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072680/using-mongodb-objectid-as-a-document-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand from your question is that if have a document from Mongodb that becomes an object in your application. To identify this object across the application, you want to use this _id so that changes to this object can be tracked easily. If this is the case, you should be using it happily. Because the ObjectId's of Mongodb are unique.
Infact, I do use this _id in my android application. example code here

```
studentUniqueId.setText(dataModelItem.get_Id());
```

where studentUniqueId is a hidden field in my android application.